# discrepancies in rounding off in C

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding

I'm having an issue where when I print a double value it is inconsistently either rounding up or down. I am using the format:

```
printf("%.2lf", double);
```

what could be the possible issue here? thanks!

Comment: example is like when the value is 1203.505000 it becomes 1203.50 but at other times it could become 1203.51

Comment: That fraction probably can't be represented exactly in binary floating point. So it's really something like `1203.505000000001` (which rounds up) or `1203.50499999999` (which rounds down). Floating point arithmetic accumulates roundoff errors like that.

Comment: If this is a problem, you probably shouldn't be using floating point in the first place. If this is money, use integer with the values multiplied by 100.

Comment: the fraction is exact at the 3rd decimal point and I'm required to use double

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates that you get different results with the same value.

Comment: Note that the rounding of the fraction can be different depending on the integer part.

Comment: As I said, the rounding of the fraction depends on the integer part.

Comment: The internal representation of `1873.585000` is something like `1873.58499999999`, while `2287.395000` is `2287.395000000001`

Comment: Try printing your values with `%.20lf` format and you'll see what's happening.

Comment: *the fraction is exact at the 3rd decimal point* Actually, it's not.  It's exact at the 53rd *bit*, but there's no such thing as a third decimal point for it to be exact at. *I'm required to use double* Whoever is requiring this of you might have thrown you a real curveball.

Answer (score 1):

Any decimal numeral in source code or input is converted to the binary format your C implementation uses for `double`. This changes the value away from the xxx.xx5 value. When it is then printed using `%.2lf`, it is the changed value that is rounded, not the original. There is no way to avoid this using only the value in a `double`.

With additional information, such as known limits on how many decimal digits the original numerals had or what values they may take, it might be possible to reconstruct the original value and round that. However, such information is not present in the question.

Answer (score 0):

"[fraction is exact at the 3rd decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70269105/discrepancies-in-rounding-off-in-c/70269698#comment124216965_70269105)"

As `double` uses a binary internal representation, most decimal fractions like 0.1, 0.01, 0.001 are not possible to represent exactly.  Instead of the exact code value of `x.xx5`, a `double` *near* that is used, perhaps a tad lower or higher.

To recover that *exact at the 3rd decimal point*, scale the `double` by 1000.0 and round to nearest whole number.

```
double d1000 = round(d * 1000.0);
```

To print to 2 decimal places, round the `d1000` to the nearest 10s, round and then divide by 100.0

```
double d100 = round(d1000 / 10.0) / 100.0;
printf("%.2lf", double);
```

In effect, code recovers by employing a [double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding).

---

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void prt(double d) {
  double d1000 = round(d * 1000.0);
  double d100 = round(d1000 / 10.0) / 100.0;
  printf("%.16e %.2lf\n", d, d100);
}

void prt3(double d) {
  prt(nextafter(d, 0));
  prt(d);
  prt(nextafter(d, d*2));
}

int main() {
  prt3(1203.505000);
  prt3(1203.705000);
}
```

Output

```
1.2035049999999999e+03 1203.51
1.2035050000000001e+03 1203.51
1.2035050000000003e+03 1203.51
1.2037049999999997e+03 1203.71
1.2037049999999999e+03 1203.71
1.2037050000000002e+03 1203.71
```

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you wrote

> the fraction is exact at the 3rd decimal point

Your original number might have been, but once it's converted to `double`, which uses binary fractions internally, there's no such thing as a "third decimal point", and in fact decimal numbers like 0.001 and 0.005 simply cannot be represented exactly.

Here are some sample numbers, how they're represented as a `double`, and how they print as `"%.2lf`, that is, converted back to decimal and rounded to two places.

(Note that when I say "how they're represented as a `double`", what I'm really showing you is the internal binary representation converted back to decimal again.  It's also interesting to look at the *actual* internal representation, in binary or hexadecimal, but it's harder to display meaningfully and doesn't really bear on today's question, so I'm not going to bother.)

| input value | internal `double` value | printed `"%.2lf"` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1203.480 | `1203.4800000000000181899` | 1203.48 |
| 1203.485 | `1203.4849999999998999556` | 1203.48 |
| 1203.490 | `1203.4900000000000090949` | 1203.49 |
| 1203.495 | `1203.4949999999998908606` | 1203.49 |
| 1203.500 | `1203.5000000000000000000` | 1203.50 |
| 1203.505 | `1203.5050000000001091394` | 1203.51 |
| 1203.510 | `1203.5099999999999909051` | 1203.51 |
| 1203.515 | `1203.5150000000001000444` | 1203.52 |
| 1203.520 | `1203.5199999999999818101` | 1203.52 |
| 1203.525 | `1203.5250000000000909495` | 1203.53 |
| 1203.530 | `1203.5299999999999727152` | 1203.53 |

You can see that sometimes `.xx5` is represented as `.xx50000000001` and so rounds up as you expect, but sometimes it's represented as `.xx49999999999` and so rounds down.

You asked "what could be the possible issue here", and that's what I've explained.  Other answers contain suggestions on how you could adjust your code to work around the issue.